# Wrap section title around figure

Tags: latex

I have a twosided document and want to add some wrapfigures. The speciality is that I want wrapped section titles on left pages.

The example shows the problem for the second section. For the first and third everything is fine.

MWE:

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{scrbook}

    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{blindtext}

    \begin{document}
        \chapter{First Chapter}
        \section{First Section}
        \begin{wrapfigure}[14]{o}{0.4\linewidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{picture}
            \end{center}
            \vspace*{-1em}
            \captionsetup{width=0.75\linewidth}
            \caption[short]{long.}
        \end{wrapfigure}

        \blindtext[5]


        \section{Second Section}
        \begin{wrapfigure}[14]{o}{0.4\linewidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{picture}
            \end{center}
            \vspace*{-1em}
            \captionsetup{width=0.75\linewidth}
            \caption[short]{long.}
        \end{wrapfigure}

        \blindtext

        \section{Third Section}
        \begin{wrapfigure}[14]{o}{0.4\linewidth}
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth]{picture}
            \end{center}
            \vspace*{-1em}
            \captionsetup{width=0.75\linewidth}
            \caption[short]{long.}
        \end{wrapfigure}

        \blindtext

    \end{document}
```

Result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3x7s.jpg

Comment: I think you'll have a better chance asking this in the tex.se site. I voted to migrate it.